# How to create database in oracle 10G

Tags: oracle10g

I am trying to create tabase in Oracle 10g using query

Create database testdb

but it showing error CREATE DATABASE failed
database already mounted

Please help me..

Comment: First off, are you really sure that you want to create a database?  What many other relational databases call a "database" is more similar to a "schema" in Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "STARTUP NOMOUNT" first.

Follow the directions in [the Oracle docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/create.htm#g1034097).  Or, much easier - use [the DBCA](http://docs.oracle.com/html/A89868_02/dbcacrea.htm) (Database Configuration Assistant).

Answer (score 2):

Your database instance is already mounted to a database. In order to create a database you have to start an instance without mounting a database and then issue the create databse command.

```
$ SQLPLUS /nolog
> CONNECT SYS/password AS SYSDBA
> STARTUP NOMOUNT
> CREATE DATABASE ...
```

Comment: what actually the command `> CONNECT SYS/password AS SYSDBA` means? I'm getting error `insufficient privileges`.